# Does specifying full webpage path in robots.txt would affect my website?

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

It may be a silly question but I need to clarify my doubt because it's related to *robots.txt*.

I need to prevent some label path of my website using *robots.txt* file.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /directory/wp-admin/path/label
```

If I give like this, would it affect all the paths separately?

Which means, does Googlebot consider `directory`, `wp-admin`, `path` and `label` separately?

Comment: Hello John, you ask many questions about _robots.txt_ these days, don't hesitate to read pages of [this website](http://www.robotstxt.org) to understand general functionalities of _robots.txt_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path specified in the `Disallow:` field is simply a URL prefix. So, any URL that starts with this prefix will be blocked.

```
Disallow: /directory/wp-admin/path/label
```

From your example, this will therefore block all of the following URLs:

```
/directory/wp-admin/path/label
/directory/wp-admin/path/labelfoo
/directory/wp-admin/path/label/
/directory/wp-admin/path/label/bar.html
```

But will not block:

```
/directory/wp-admin/path/foo
/directory/wp-admin/path/
/directory/wp-admin/hello.html
:
```

Googlebot does not see the separate directories that make up the path. It is simply one value, one **URL prefix**.

More information on the Google Developers website:
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

Answer (score -1):

Robots.txt treats each path directive individually...

So, for example:-

```
User-agent:*
Disallow: /directory/wp-admin/path/label
```

This would disallow crawling of the directory `label` but not everything preceeding this directory nor following it.

```
User-agent:*
Disallow: /directory/wp-admin/path/label/*
```

This would disallow the crawling of everything within the directory `label` , including sub directories and their contents and the directory itself.

Comment: This is not correct, `Disallow: /directory/wp-admin/path/label` **will** block everything "following it". It will block everything that `.../label/*` blocks and more. The non-standard wildcard `*` at the end of the value is superfluous.